# Flask 400 Bad Request when sent from C# App, but 200 from Postman?

Tags: c#, flask

I am posting the following JSON to my Flask server:

```
{"comment": "astute observation", "ua": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36", "cookie": "ua=f8256d37159e3faf28ae61a6406601c3; platform=pc; bs=bxa7ziiq07dufk31prvoo0mbfm44sayh; ss=994139249854417186; il=v1qyca8PU7X6jSwgiqceXsySwWB60HnCjSJ1HjNmsSxRUxNjQzNjA3OTEycUVTTFoxWUpSZDFTZ3kwclIzenBHa19FbnlmMTlIN0hZeHNDQ1FOLQ..; expiredEnterModalShown=1", "parent": "860245961"}
```

When sent from Postman, the request works flawlessly.  However, when sent from my C# app, like so, the server returns a 400 Bad Request error code.

```
var data = $"{{\"comment\": \"{text}\", \"ua\": \"{userAgent}\", \"cookie\": \"{cookie}\", \"parent\": \"{parent}\"}}";
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/";
var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
await using var sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
await sw.WriteAsync(data);
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

To make sure that the JSON is properly formatted, I set a breakpoint and inspected the "data" variable.  I copied/pasted that value into Postman, set the Content-Type to application/json, and the request succeeds from there, but fails from my C# application.

Server code:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process():
    print(request.json)
    return 'Hello'

app.run(debug=True)
```

Edit:  After posting this, I realized I wasn't sending a user agent from my C# app.  I tried adding one and the server still responds with a 400 Bad Request error.

Edit 2:  I tried simplifying the data variable for testing purposes.  `var data = "{\"msg\": \"david\"}";` and setting `request.ContentLength = data.Length`, still having the same problem.  Really strange.

Comment: Not familiar with this variant of strings in C# - the one beginning with a $.  Does data expand out with the contents substituted in or is that done somewhere else

Comment: could you provide a sample of the final value of `data`?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann It is included in my post, that was taken from setting a breakpoint and copying the value of data from my IDE.

Comment: @cup It is a template string, the value of data after the relevant line is executed is included at the top of my post.  The double curly brackets evaluate to single curly brackets here, because single curly brackets are used to inject variables.  Little confusing when dealing with JSON, but it is producing a valid JSON string (same one that I am sending with Postman and not getting 400 Bad Request).

Answer (score 0):

Very odd, but this solved the problem.  Using the StreamWriter class was causing the issue.  Doing this instead results in a 200 OK response finally.

```
using var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
await stream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
```